# How do I put &gt and &lt as text in HTML?

Tags: html

I was wondering how I can display the `&gt` and the `&lt` tags a regular text?
I've tried using the `<plaintext>` tag, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Put it as "&amp;gt;"